# Query with join in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have these tables:

1. Customer Details

   ```
   CustCode, Name , Address, CityID
   ```
2. MasterCity

   ```
   CityName, CityId
   ```
3. OrderDetails

   ```
   OrderDetails, CustCode , OrderNo, Somedetails , DeliveryStation
   ```

`Deliverystation` is that where order has to be placed. Here I send `CityId`
and Customer Details also contains `CityId` and **not** `cityname`.

Now I want to select data from `OrderDetails`. I join `OrderDetails` and `Customer Details` On `Customer Details.CustCode = OrderDetails.CustCod`e  and `Customer Details` and  MasterCity on `MasterCity.CityId = Customer Details.CityId`.

this work fine but i also want to join `OrderDetails` and `MasterCity` to get `DeliveryStation` City Name.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another join to MasterCity with an alias, eg

```
Select a.CustCode, a.Name, a.Address, A.CityId,c.OrderNo, c.SomeDetails,d.CityName DeliveryStation
  from CustomerDetails a
  join MasterCity b
    on a.CityID=b.CityID
  join OrderDetail c
    on a.CustCode=c.CustCode
  join MasterCity d
    on d.CityId=c.DeliveryStation
```